# Creating a navigation drawer with icons and text

Tags: android

I am creating a navigation drawer in my android app and want to be able to define the menu options in a resource file. So far I have done it with a string array as follows

```
<string-array name="drawer_options">
        <item>Option 1</item>
        <item>Option 2</item>
        <item>Option 3</item>
        <item>Option 4</item>
    </string-array>
```

Which works fine as I can create an Arrayadapter and pass that in to the drawer adapter setter. What I want however is to be able to also specify an icon to sit alongside each option in the drawer so they are not just text options. In C# I would create a new object eg. "NavigationDrawerOption" with a text and image property, then pass in an array of that. Is that the same sort of thing I should do here? If so, how can I specify a key-value mapping in a resource config file, ie not just a string array but an array of string/image options?

Comment: You can look at this library for quick creating navigation drawer logic: https://github.com/Arasthel/GoogleNavigationDrawerMenu

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

You will need to create a custom List Adapter that will contain an ImageView and a TextView.